# Karate-DSL doesn't return the response in an order

Tags: karate, web-api-testing

Suppose that I have a GET endpoint to and the result looks like below

```
[
  {
    "id": 42,
    "studentName": "John",
    "alternateName1": "",
    "alternateName2": "",
    "code": "NS2",
    "year": 2019
  },
  {
    "id": 41,
    "studentName": "John",
    "alternateName1": "",
    "alternateName2": "",
    "code": "NS1",
    "year": 2019
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "studentName": "Tom",
    "alternateName1": "",
    "alternateName2": "",
    "code": "NS2",
    "year": 2019
  }
]
```

The response doesn't return in an order based on ID or name.... so, when performing the match to compare it to result of corresponding query in database, it turns "FAILED". Try some tools like Postman to check the order, it follows "id" and same as the natural SQL query.

Also, follow and customize the js function 'sort-array.feature' to sort the response, but the response type is an array; thus, it doesn't work.

I would like to know how we handle the order of the response based on configured values (like: id) or a default value (like, "name") as in my case, or any approach to compare the result of an API endpoint(actual result) to result of a query (expected result)

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the docs and examples and especially look out for `contains`. I'm providing one example below, the rest is homework for you (especially since you like Postman so much :P). Paste this into a fresh scenario and see it work.

```
* def response =
"""
[
  {
    "id": 42,
    "studentName": "John",
    "alternateName1": "",
    "alternateName2": "",
    "code": "NS2",
    "year": 2019
  },
  {
    "id": 41,
    "studentName": "John",
    "alternateName1": "",
    "alternateName2": "",
    "code": "NS1",
    "year": 2019
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "studentName": "Tom",
    "alternateName1": "",
    "alternateName2": "",
    "code": "NS2",
    "year": 2019
  }
]
"""
* match response[*].id contains only [1, 41, 42]
```

Karate allows you to create and even transform JSON in multiple ways, so you can pretty much do any comparison you want.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I also check with contain BUT not try with  "contain only" yet. Normally, we must have expected result (DB query) and actual result (API calling) to check, so that's why I would like the response on expected and actual should be exactly the same to make sure no cheat or accidentally passed :). So, I hope Karate board can consider a sorting function to compare in the future. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion :)